# See if PayPal payment came from eBay for PayPal IPN

Tags: paypal, listener, paypal-ipn

How do you stop eBay PayPal payments going to the IPN listener? (preferred but probably not possible?)
Or - How do I get my listener to ask where the payment comes from? 
If from eBay do nothing / just verify (or store in table in hope of extending my order management system in future, say)
If from myshop log order for invoice, sending, etc.

What IPN variable can I use? Check for length of item number, perhaps? umm

Answer (score 1):

If it comes from eBay there will be a `for_auction` parameter included that is set to true.  You will also `ebay_txn_idn`, where n is the number of the item(s) array.  Also an `auction_buyer_id` will be included.  Plenty of options to flag those.

Here is an example of an IPN that came from an eBay auction:

```
Array
(
    [mc_gross] => 440.99
    [protection_eligibility] => Eligible
    [for_auction] => true
    [address_status] => confirmed
    [item_number1] => 232029148438
    [tax] => 0.00
    [payer_id] => 83W5CCCCCCCS6
    [ebay_txn_id1] => 1370976126013
    [address_street] => 123 Test Ave
    [payment_date] => 23:52:09 Oct 20, 2016 PDT
    [payment_status] => Completed
    [charset] => windows-1252
    [address_zip] => 59840-2149
    [mc_shipping] => 21.00
    [first_name] => David
    [mc_fee] => 10.00
    [auction_buyer_id] => comasdfr33
    [address_country_code] => US
    [address_name] => Tester Testerson
    [notify_version] => 3.8
    [custom] => EBAY_EMSCX0000687394734010
    [payer_status] => unverified
    [business] => sales@domain.com
    [address_country] => United States
    [num_cart_items] => 1
    [address_city] => Hamilton
    [verify_sign] => A0av94YibvcTZFf.ILwh4u8suh06AqfSvHzsAv3r.zSG91GuDFSbZ.Mw
    [payer_email] => asdfg@gmx.com
    [contact_phone] => 408-636-6400
    [txn_id] => 9EX39945FA6779640
    [payment_type] => instant
    [last_name] => Testerson
    [address_state] => MT
    [item_name1] => Zebra GX420d USB/Serial/Ethernet Mono Direct Printer
    [receiver_email] => sales@domain.com
    [payment_fee] => 10.00
    [quantity1] => 1
    [receiver_id] => EMY7DGXTF8ZVE
    [insurance_amount] => 0.00
    [txn_type] => cart
    [item_name] => Zebra GX420d USB/Serial/Ethernet Mono Direct Printer
    [mc_gross_1] => 419.99
    [mc_currency] => USD
    [item_number] => 232029148438
    [residence_country] => US
    [receipt_id] => 0428-5320-1923-6500
    [transaction_subject] => 
    [payment_gross] => 440.99
    [ipn_track_id] => 9429e4ed195db
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Oh so is that just for eBay auctions? or for any eBay sale do you know? Cheers

Comment: but sure - the ebay_tax_idn sounds like it would do the trick

Comment: It would be for any eBay sale.